# @Optional() basePath: string resolves into error when compiling with AOT

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have an Angular (v4.0.1) app with a generated API (swagger-code-gen). It works perfectly when I build it with JIT compiler (both prod and dev configurations). 
But when I try to compile it with the AOT compiler I get the following error in the generated swagger API;

> Starting compilation using the angular compiler. Angular compilation
>   done, starting webpack bundling. Error: Can't resolve all parameters
>   for ThisAwasomeGeneratedApi in
>   /Users/.../Documents/Development/ProjectAwesomeness/src/app/modals/api/ThisAwasomeGeneratedApi.ts:
>   ([object Object], ?).
>       at syntaxError (/Users/.../Documents/Development/ProjectAwesomeness/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1513:34)

//generated api (swagger-codegen generate -i)

```
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import {Injectable, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as models from '../model/models';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable member-ordering */

'use strict';

@Injectable()
export class ThisAwasomeGeneratedApi {
    public basePath = 'http://localhost:8080/awasomeapi';
    public defaultHeaders : Headers = new Headers();

    constructor(protected http: Http, @Optional() basePath: string) {
        if (basePath) {
            this.basePath = basePath;
        }
    }  
 ..code omitted  
}
```

**When I delete the "@Optional() basePath: string" everything works fine with AOT.**

The @Optional decorator returns null if it couldn't find it's dependency. So why can't it build when the dependency is optional?

Information about the optional decorator:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Optional-decorator.html

Comment: Is `@Optional() basePath: string` different to `basePath?: string`, I actually don't know?

Comment: `@Optional() @Inject('basePath') basePath: string`

Comment: @Zze No, I think not. It only another implementation of a nullable value? I did try that and it resolves in the same error..

Comment: @yurzui Thank you for providing the a good answer to my question. The _@inject('basePath')_ solved the AOT compile issue. Now I have to look for a solution that Swagger-code-gen does generate this inject too.